# Databricks- Spark SQL Update statement error

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

This is a pretty straightforward update statement that works on SQL Server DB and I have re-written it in Databricks which is not working, Can you provide your suggestions?

```
update 
a

set 
    composite_account_key=nvl(e.account_key,0)
edw.account_fact a
join edw.account_dim b on (a.account_key=b.account_key)
join vw_account_hier c on (b.accountcode=c.accountcode)
join edw.analysis_codes_dim d on (d.anlys_code_dimkey=a.anlys_code_dimkey and c.atomic_anlys_appl_cde=d.anlys_appl_cde)
join vw_composite e on (c.edw_c_account_code=e.edw_c_account_code)
where 
a.timekey='95'
```

ParseException:[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'from'(line 5, pos 0)

Comment: @Kiran A, can you provide the sample input and schema of your table and expected result in codes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The syntax of `update` statement in Databricks SQL does not support using `from` parameter.
- You can create a temporary view from the result of all the join operations and use this view in the update statement directly instead.
- The following is the demonstration of the same. I have the result of my join query as shown below:

[image]

- When I try to use `from` parameter directly in update statement (update id value to 10 wherever it is 1 from join result), I get the same error.

[image]

- So, I have created a view first and then used it in update query to get the result.

```
%sql

--CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW for_updt as (select a.id,a.gname,b.team from demo as a join demo1 as b on a.id=b.id );

update demo set id=10 where id in(select id from for_updt where) and (demo.id=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks!! 
This has worked for me and I even tried with the merge statement as well, both of them worked!!